# How to fail any Django REST Framework requests with unknown parameters?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django REST Framework API ignores any unknown parameters. This has led to several issues. For example, when a model filter was missing, a client received all records rather than the single one they were expecting. **How can I force DRF to return *400 Bad Request* whenever an API call includes an unknown parameter?**

(An unknown parameter is one which is not in `[SerializerClass].Meta.fields` if this is a list, or not in `[SerializerClass].Meta.model` fields if it is `__all__`.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the easy and basic solution may be this,

```
# serializer.py

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'


# views.py
def foo_view(request):
    serializer = FooSerializer(data=request.data)
    if set(request.data.keys()) - set(serializer.fields.keys()):
        raise Exception
```

---

**Note:** Assuming **`request.data`** is a `dict` object

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm not sure about the cases while we use [**`source`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument in serializer

Comment: That looks like an expensive operation for every single API endpoint, but yeah, it should work.

Comment: Yeah, It's expensive. I wouldn't recommend this solution since it's not covered in many cases.